# Elasticsearch can not update nested field

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elastic 6.7 and trying to update a single nested field using dot separator like this

```
POST p_app/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": """

   if (ctx._source?.info.status != null) 
    {  
        ctx._source.remove('info.status');
        ctx._source.put('info.status', 'updated_value');
    }   
    """,
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": {
    "terms": {
        "_id": [
          "1011"
        ]
      }
  }
}
```

But instead of updating the `status` field inside `info` object, it creates a new field named `info.status` with the given value. How do I properly specify the nested field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to specify parent object as source like this

```
if (ctx._source?.info?.status != null) 
    {  
        ctx._source?.info.remove('status');
        ctx._source?.info.put('status', 'updated_value');
    }
```